# How can I display size on the Rect shape by fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When I use `FabricJS` to create a Rect shape, I want to display the width and height of the Rect like in the image below. If I scale Rect, the text should update. How can I do this?

[image: image dimensions]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Take a look at http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas for how to overlay a dom object over a Fabric object, and http://fabricjs.com/events for how to use events (a scaling event can update the overlay's text)

Answer (score 0):

For getting the selected or active image size we can use below code

```
// for getting active objects, here its Rectangle

this.selectedObj= this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject().objects;

// if there is one object we get the resultant values like this.
var width = this.selectedData.objects[0].width;
var height = this.selectedData.objects[0].height;
```